# Splitting vector into blocks - is this correct?

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

I am converting a function from MatLab to C++ that takes a vector and separates into blocks containing 600 values and changing at intervals of 200. Here is the function (In MatLab):

```
function f = block(v, N, M)

% This function separates the vector  
% into blocks.  Each block has size N.
% and consecutive blocks differ in
% their starting positions by M
% 
% Typically
%    N = 30 msec (600 samples)
%    M = 10 msec (200 samples)

n = length(v);
maxblockstart = n - N + 1;
lastblockstart = maxblockstart - mod(maxblockstart-1 , M);

% Remove the semicolon to see the number of blocks
% numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1
numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;

f = zeros(numblocks,N);

for i = 1:numblocks
 for j = 1:N
  f(i,j) = v((i-1)*M+j);
end
```

end

And the function in C++:

```
vector< iniMatrix > Audio::something(vector<double>& theData, int N, int M)
{
//How many blocks of size N can we get?
int num_blocks = theData.size() / N;

int n = theData.size();
int maxblockstart = n - N;
int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - (maxblockstart % M);
int numbblocks = (lastblockstart)/M + 1;

this->width = N;

//Create the vector with enough empty slots for num_blocks blocks
vector<iniMatrix> blocked(num_blocks);

//Loop over all the blocks
for(int i = 0; i < num_blocks; i++) {
    //Resize the inner vector to fit this block            
    blocked[i].resize(N);

    //Pull each sample for this block
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        blocked[i][j] = theData[i*N+j];
    }
}
return blocked;
```

}

Does this look correct? I know it's a weird question, and I'll probably get negative feedback BUT, I tried counting the number of zero-crossings and it displayed the wrong answer, so, maybe there is something wrong with how I'm splitting the vector.

EDIT:

iniMatrix is a typedef of a 2D vector

Produces 96 blocks (containing 600 values)

Comment: blocked[i][j] = theData[i*N+j]; N is typo?

Comment: @DanilAsotsky What do you mean? "blocked[i][j] = theData[i*N+j];" is not a typo.. is there a mistake?

Comment: You have v((i-1)*M+j) in Matlab code (last loop in code), but in C++ code it is theData[i*N+j]. It seems there is misprint that can lead to error. E.g., you need to have theData[i*M+j].

Comment: @DanilAsotsky Thank you :D! Will you put it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
f(i,j) = v((i-1)*M+j);
```

in last loop of the Matlab code, but in C++ code it is

```
blocked[i][j] = theData[i*N+j];
```

It seems there is misprint that can lead to error. E.g., you need to have code in C++:

```
blocked[i][j] = theData[i*M+j];
```